# Связи SQL в Managment Studio

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, datatable

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста по данной схеме заполняя например таблицу командировка автоматически не заполняются связанная с ней таблица указы. Надо чтобы заполняя любую таблицу в данной схеме таблица "Накази" заполнядась автоматически.

Comment: *Надо чтобы заполняя любую таблицу в данной схеме таблица "Накази" заполнядась автоматически.* Не надо. Именно для этого (вернее, в том числе и для этого) и существуют связи.

Comment: Как бы они уже свзаны, но таблицы автоматически не заполняются.

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что они должны заполняться автоматически по связям?

Comment: пишите триггеры, если хотите чтобы что-то заполнялось автоматически.